# Drupal Display suite title formatter

Tags: drupal-7, display-suite

I am writing a title formatter for display suite, but title isn't a 'CCK' type. Can anyone help me out with how to define the formatter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since title is a property, not a field, you cannot use a field formatter.

You'll need to take another approach to solve this problem, for example override the node template file, implement a hook_preprocess function, or implement hook_node_view.

edit:
There are lots of discussions about properties versus fields.
Here are some links to get you started with some background about why title is still a property, as well as some related modules.

- http://drupal.org/node/557292 - Issue: Convert node title to fields
- http://drupal.org/node/571654 - Issue: Revert node titles as fields

Note: I have not used all these modules and do not endorse them in any way, and don't claim that they address your question. This is just a short listing for your edification:

- http://drupal.org/project/title
- http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle
- http://drupal.org/project/title_field_ui

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean the title isn't a "CCK" type? It should be a Field. Try this module: http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters

Comment: The title field is different from other fields. Custom formatters can't be used to create formatters for titles.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue for the custom formatters module about that: [#816924: Custom formatter for title field?](http://drupal.org/node/816924)